# Simulating gravity in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, game-physics

I'm trying to animate a 2d sprite in my XNA 2D game, by the force of gravity. I've developed a very basic class to achieve the simulation effect. This is my sample code.

```
namespace Capture
{
class PhysX
{
    static Vector2 g = new Vector2(0.0f, 10.0f);
    public Vector2 pos, vel, acc, accumForce;
    public float mass;
    public bool USE_GRAVITY = true;

    /* Constructor */
    public void Engage(ref GameTime gameTime, uint maxX, uint maxY)
    {

        Vector2 F = Vector2.Zero;
        if (USE_GRAVITY)
        {
            F = accumForce + mass * g;
        }

        acc = F / mass;//This is the Net acceleration, Using Newtons 2nd Law
        vel += acc * gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds;// v = u + a*t
        pos += vel * gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds;// s = u*t + 0.5*a*t*t, 
        pos.X %= maxX;
        pos.Y %= maxY;

    }

    public void ApplyForce(ref Vector2 f)
    {
        accumForce += f;
    }
}
}
```

I'm calling the `PhysX#Engage()` method in `Game#Update(GameTime gt)` method. 
The problem is this I'm not getting a smooth animation. This is because the position gets very large soon. To, overcome that I tried to take modulus, as show in the code with the `Viewport.Width, Viewport.Height` but still the position coordinates are not at all smooth. What should I do. How to make animation smooth? Please help.

Comment: What is your mass set to? the higher the mass, the slower the acceleration.

Comment: @SteveH the mass term in the force and the division by mass cancel out. Gravity acceleration doesn't depend on the mass.

Comment: @Anurag Your speed increases linearly with time. Usually you introduce a slowing term that's linear in speed to simulate friction and limit the terminal velocity.

Comment: I don't get what maxX and maxY are used for. Could you explain to me please? what kind of value are they called with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's happening because you are taking elapsed time value as integer.

Try use double value of seconds that takes into account even the fractionary part:

```
flaot dt = (float)GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
vel += acc * dt;// v = u + a*t
pos += vel * dt;// s = u*t + 0.5*a*t*t,
```

In addition:

> This is because the position gets very large soon.

Well, you should keep the float value as close as possible to [-1,+1] range, otherwise you will get a loose of precision. 
My advice is:

1. keep the float properties of your objects in a small range([-1,+1])
2. transform your values before drawing depending on your resolution